# Data lost when restarting Python Flask/SQLAlchemy project

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I've inherited a Flask/SQLAlchemy website and am attempting to bring it up. The project is running fine, with all functionality working as expected. The database doesn't seem to persist, however.

If I create a new object (a customer in this case) on the site, everything displays correctly. If I kill the application and bring it back up, all created data disappears.

I'm sure this is some sort of configuration on the site, but I am not familiar enough with Flask to remedy.

This is a enterprise application, so can't post the code, but could I get some general tips to look into?

---

**Update**

Here is a sample SQLAlchemy log when creating a new object:

```
...
2017-10-18 18:29:42,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO 
captains_rosters_links (created, modified, position, on_duty, 
roster_id, captain_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
2017-10-18 18:29:42,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 18, 29, 42, 827068), None, 4, 1, 2L, 
3L)
2017-10-18 18:29:42,828 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

I switched the application to the production environment and it appears to be executing commits now.

When I kill the application and bring it back up, though, the data doesn't persist.

Comment: Actually, it _almost_ looks like maybe there is sample data overwriting my database _every_ time it starts. Which would not be desired. Im unsure if this is custom code or standard flask though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, is there a commit() call on the SQLAlchemy session?

Setting the Flask configuration attribute 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO' to True will cause all DB queries to be printed to stdout:

```
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(application)
```

With SQLALCHEMY_ECHO enabled, you can watch the DB traffic to see if updating  an object in a SQLAlchemy session causes the DB to be updated and eventually COMMITed or rolled back.

Comment: updated issue to respond to this. i switched to the production environment and now see the commits going, but killing the program and bringing it back up reverts all the data

Comment: Can you look at the DB independently of your app?  e.g., look after you shut down the app but before you restart.

Comment: Okay, looks like I have data in the database _before_ restarting. So something about the start process is clearing the database

Comment: See if the environment variable APP_CONFIG points to a config file that's recreating the DB before the app is launched.

Comment: It's difficult to tell (like I said I inherited this project and am not familiar with flask), but the `database.py` file calls `database_sample_data.build_defaults_db`. Commenting this out doesn't seem to prevent the database from clearing though. I'm unsure what would be farther upstream than this.

Comment: Found it! There was code explicitly dropping tables on launch. I'm unsure why it was added, but that's a different sort of question. I appreciate your help, it definitely made finding the issue possible :)